# Index Match to return MAX Date with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, formula

apologies for this, I'm assuming this is simple but a few hours of SO googling hasn't helped

Enough whining from me:

Consider the following dataset:

```
ID, Date, Review, Review    Status
1   01/02/18, "Cool",       Positive
1   01/03/18, "Awesome", "  Positive
1   01/01/18, "Cumbersome", Negative
1   01/02/18, "Rubbish!", " Negative
```

I'm currently using an array type index match to get the latest review based on a few conditions

I have two columns one which says positive, one negative.

in each of the column I would like to return the latest positive review but I'm unsure how to get the max date within the below formula:

```
{=index(C2:C4, MATCH(1,(1 = A2:A4)*("Positive" = D2:D4)*(maxdatehere = B2:B4),0))}
```

The data I have is around 7k rows and is Google Review Data and pretty much matches the example above.

I'd rather not use VBA as I've never really used it before (but will do so grudgingly)

as this is excel I've not created a google demo sheet, but happy to do so for ease of the experts and for others to benfit if they find there way here one day.

Comment: Thanks for the tip my man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Office 365:

```
=INDEX(C2:C5, MATCH(1,(1 = A2:A5)*("Positive" = D2:D5)*(MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,1,D:D,"Positive") = B2:B5),0))
```

Confirme with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If you have 2010 or later then:

```
=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(C2:C5)/((A2:A5=1)*(D2:D5="Positive")*(AGGREGATE(14,7,B2:B5/((A2:A5=1)*(D2:D5="Positive")),1)=B2:B5)),1))
```

Entered normally.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! you are the man, may I ask can you add a -1 to get the max date -1? I'd like to return the 3 most recent reviews on a customer experience excel dashboard. this is for the pre 365 version

Comment: That is a new question but it is definitely possible, depending on how you want the values returned(separate cells or one cell).  Separate cells change the `..(AGGREGATE(14,7,B2:B5/((A2:A5=1)*(D2:D5="Positive")),1)=B2:B5))..` to `(AGGREGATE(14,7,B2:B5/((A2:A5=1)*(D2:D5="Positive")),ROW(1:1))=B2:B5))` after putting that in the first cell, just copy the formula down two more cells and you will get the last three.

Comment: Seperate cells for sure as some of the reviews are quite verbose! let me try the above thanks for answering my initial question regardless

Comment: Perfect worked like a charm, seriously this is some high level excel magic, hat tip to you good sir.